# Getting a game maker android error

Tags: android, game-maker

When I attempt to build my project, I get the following error. Can anyone help?

```
    A problem occurred configuring project ':com.companyname.ReignOfDystopia'.
> failed to find target with hash string 'android-23' in: C:\Users\RyanW\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: do you have Android 6.0 API installed?

Comment: You shouldn't use the companyname.com domain if you don't own it

Comment: @Bálint, for testing purposes, such a domain is completely fine. The domain name is actually used to differentiate between different packages, not for the purpose of web association. In fact, many sites instruct you to use "companyname.com" or "domain.com", including professional tutorial sites. [Read more about it at Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30270936/android-studio-company-domain-name).

Comment: I have everything installed, i still get this error but it packs the apk and i have installed it onto my mobile.

Comment: Also, companyname.com is the default domain for testing. I have re configured this all after the initial testing phase run today anyway.

Comment: If it packs and installs, what is it your asking for help with?

Comment: and what is "everything"?

Comment: I have all the versions of android required, and the NDK installed. And im getting a few compatibility issues on my device due to that error, or so i believe. Im not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Why is this getting so many downvotes?

Comment: Probably because `Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.` but you don't show that you actually did that to get more info on the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i figured out the build error. I recompiled the project, and after building the error was no longer being given to me.